# How to get when a key is let go (onkeyup) while holding command?

Tags: javascript, dom, keyboard-events

It seems like `onkeyup` doesn't fire while holding command (at least in chrome on a mac). Is there anyway to get when any key is let go (onkeyup) while holding command?

Observe below:

If you hold command then press a character key, when you let of the character key, an `onkeyup` event doesn't fire.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const {key, metaKey} = e;
  console.log({key, metaKey});
})
```

Specifically, I'm trying to see if the user is about holding `z` in while performing an `Cmd + z` keyboard shortcut. In my UI, I also have a clickable undo button. While the user is holding `cmd + z`, I want to style the button in an `:active` state but when they let go of `z` (while still possibly holding `cmd`), I want to remove that active state.

To clarify: I know how to check for a `cmd + z` in a keyboard event. Now I want an event *after* the user presses `cmd + z` to let me know *when they let go of z* while they could still be holding `cmd`.

To do that, I thought I could listen for `keyup` events but the `keyup` event doesn't seem to fire while holding `cmd`.

What am I missing and how can I get around this?

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006583/capturing-ctrlz-key-combination-in-javascript

Comment: @AlexBieg thanks for the reference but that's not what I'm looking for. I know how to check for a `cmd + z` in a keyboard event but what I'm trying to do now is see if the user is holding `z` or not while also holding `cmd`. I apologize, it's subtle difference.

Comment: Is cmd on mac similar to the windows key? If so I imagine the OS is intercepting it, that's probably not something you can get around.

Comment: @phuhgh yeah it is and i think that's the case :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Javascript drop keyUp events when the metaKey is pressed on Mac browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818637/why-does-javascript-drop-keyup-events-when-the-metakey-is-pressed-on-mac-browser)